# creating an app that it supportable by facebook mobile app

Tags: facebook, mobile

i create an application for facebook which run properly on a browser, but it is not supportable by mobile facebook application;

any advice how to run my application on facebook app, is appreciated ;
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run custom apps on the Facebook Mobile App. Instead, you should either create a native app (in Objective C of iOS or Java for Android) or create a mobile website with Facebook Connect.